# To fetch only the hours value after performing date difference in oracle sql. Then check this hours value in where clause against an integer

Tags: sql, oracle

My query is :

```
SELECT ( ( a.DATE - b.DATE ) * 24 )                   AS Date_Diff, 
       ( EXTRACT(hour FROM( a.DATE - b.DATE )) * 24 ) AS DIFF_IN_HOURS 
FROM   myquestion a, 
       myquestion b 
WHERE  a.question = 'My_DATE' 
       AND b.question = 'My_DATE' 
       AND a.setid = '124' 
       AND b.setid = '126'
```

It fetches me 1 record and below values:

for `Date_Diff I get value - 2712 0:0:0.0`
and

```
DIFF_IN_HOURS I get value - 0
```

The value in `Date_Diff - '2712'` is the exact number of hours difference between the two dates.
How do I get only this value and not the 0:0:0.0
I want to compare '2712' in another query in the where clause.

```
a.date is 08-AUG-12 12.00.00 000000000 AM

b.date is 20-NOV-12 12.00.00 000000000 AM
```

Comment: The text of your question seems to strongly imply that the two columns are defined as `DATE` in the database.  The output you are getting strongly implies that the two columns are defined as `TIMESTAMP` in the database.  What are the actual data types?  Do we need to account for fractional seconds when computing the difference?

Comment: The data type is timestamp (6). The values I have provided above for a.date and b.date are generated by the application, which I have no control on. So I am left with the whole thing to get the difference. And I need to find that the difference between two dates is x hours which is <= y

Comment: OK.  So all the references to "dates" in your question should actually refer to "timestamps", right?  What is the `y` in your `x <= y` expression?  And, as I asked initially, do we need to account for fractional seconds when computing the difference?  Or can we ignore fractional seconds?

Comment: Ok its like I have to get the difference between a timestamp value and sysdate (or any other timestamp value) and that difference should be >= 1 hour. So I am really not bothered about the fractional seconds here. Thanks.

Comment: `sysdate` is a `date`, not a `timestamp`.  `date` and `timestamp` are different data types.  A `date` has a time to the second.  A `timestamp` has a time to the nanosecond.  Are you trying to subtract one `date` from another `date`?  A `timestamp` from a `timestamp`?  A `tmiestamp` from a `date`?  Something else?

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanantion. I will be taking a difference between a timestamp and the sysdate. In one another instance also, I am required to find a difference between a timestamp and date(SYSDATE) where the difference has to be compared in days. So there are two scenarios.

Comment: 1. In which I will be comparing the timestamp with sysdate to get the difference in hours and

Comment: So, which of `a.date` and `b.date` in your original question is `sysdate` and which is the `timestamp`?

Comment: 2. Where I will be comparing the timestamp with the sysdate to get the difference in days.

Comment: a.date should be the SYSDATE, as it is expected to be a later date. And b.date will be the date(timestamp) from oracle db.